# Template is different with and without comments

Tags: sidebar, conditional-tags, theme-twenty-twelve

My referenced website is at http://angelopardo.com/wakeupbeast and I've built it as a child theme of twentytwelve.

Pages and single posts that have comments are displaying correctly, where the sidebar is just right of the posts area.

But pages and single posts that don't have comments are bumping down the sidebar below the posts area.

What conditional statement outside of the loop can I use to target pages/posts that have no comments, so that it displays the sidebar correctly? I will probably place the code in single.php or page.php

I've been stuck on this for ages, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the template code that generates the sidebar. Without code to be improved upon, how is this supposed to receive an adequate answer?

Comment: Hey Johannes, it was actually related to comments.php; a closing div tag was put in the wrong place, right after comments_open checks for posts. I removed it and placed it before that conditional code, and it seems to be working fine. :)